# libcore.java.io.InterruptedStreamTest#testInterruptWritablePipeChannel CTS test Fail

Tags: android, system-error

CTS execution using Tradefed on the device. Test on JB and CTS version is 4.1_r1. This case is always fails but sometimes can passed by lucky.

Details:

> libcore.java.io.InterruptedStreamTest#testInterruptWritablePipeChannel is failing with  the error "Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Failed to receive adb shell test output within 600000 ms. Test may have timed out, or adb connection to device became unresponsive'."

I found this on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37682), it seems that this issue is fixed by Google but somehow it still bother me since I applied the patch of this issue.

Does anyone have any ideal about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found this [link](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/43782/) on google source. It seems that this CTS test case is change needed. The comment for this case is clearly says.

> Patch Set 1:
>   CTS tests (testInterruptReadablePipeChannel and testInterruptWritablePipeChannel) are not testing the interruption cleanly. On ICS they always interrupted in framework. On JB execution mostly gets to kernel, blocks in "read" and the test fails. CTS change is needed to reliably test interruption in kernel and framework.